# CodeKata 02 in C++

Tags: c++, programming-challenge

As [before](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/196934), I am moving into C++ and would like to learn about its idioms. I have moved from Project Euler to CodeKata as the former is based on algorithms, rather than language constructs (as suggested by [bruglesco](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/u/162379) in the comments).

[Description](http://codekata.com/kata/kata02-karate-chop/) (slightly modified):

> Write a binary search method that takes an integer search target and a sorted array of integers. It should return the integer index of the target in the array, or -1 if the target is not in the array.

main.cpp:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int binarySearch(int needle, std::vector<int> values);
unsigned int middleOf(int leftBound, int rightBound);
void testBinarySearch();


int main() {
    testBinarySearch();
    return 0;
}


int binarySearch(int needle, std::vector<int> values) {
    constexpr int NOT_FOUND = -1;

    const unsigned int length = values.size();

    // If empty, needle will never be found
    if (length == 0) {
        return NOT_FOUND;
    }

    // Bracket the needle with [leftBound, rightBound]
    unsigned int leftBound = 0;
    unsigned int rightBound = length - 1;

    // Start at middle of bracket
    // If even number of entries, use the one on the left
    unsigned int position = middleOf(leftBound, rightBound);

    // Binary search ends in at most ceil of log base 2 of length + 1
    const unsigned int maxIterations = ceil(log(length) / log(2)) + 1;

    int value;
    for (unsigned int iteration = 0; iteration < maxIterations; ++iteration) {
        value = values.at(position);

        if (value == needle) {
            return position;
        } else if (value < needle) {
            leftBound = position;
            rightBound = rightBound;
            position = position + middleOf(leftBound, rightBound);
        } else if (value > needle) {
            leftBound = leftBound;
            rightBound = position;
            position = position - middleOf(leftBound, rightBound);
        }
    }

    return NOT_FOUND;
}


unsigned int middleOf(int leftBound, int rightBound) {
    return (rightBound - leftBound + 1) / 2;
}


// Test cases given on website
void testBinarySearch() {
    std::vector<int> values;
    assert(-1 == binarySearch(3, values));

    values.push_back(1);
    assert(-1 == binarySearch(3, values));
    assert( 0 == binarySearch(1, values));

    values.push_back(3);
    values.push_back(5);
    assert( 0 == binarySearch(1, values));
    assert( 1 == binarySearch(3, values));
    assert( 2 == binarySearch(5, values));
    assert(-1 == binarySearch(0, values));
    assert(-1 == binarySearch(2, values));
    assert(-1 == binarySearch(4, values));
    assert(-1 == binarySearch(6, values));

    values.push_back(7);
    assert( 0 == binarySearch(1, values));
    assert( 1 == binarySearch(3, values));
    assert( 2 == binarySearch(5, values));
    assert( 3 == binarySearch(7, values));
    assert(-1 == binarySearch(0, values));
    assert(-1 == binarySearch(2, values));
    assert(-1 == binarySearch(4, values));
    assert(-1 == binarySearch(6, values));
    assert(-1 == binarySearch(8, values));

    std::cout << "All tests passed!";
}
```

I will add files to GitLab [here](https://gitlab.com/FromTheStackAndBack/CodeKata/tree/master) and make changes to them as I receive feedback.

Comment: The problem statement itself goes against the normal C++ idioms, so I wonder about its suitability for the stated purpose.  You would implement something with the same kind of API as the `std::binary_search`, `std::equal_range`, etc. functions, returning an  iterator rather than an index, and working on any kind of container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- There is no need to pass `values` by value (pun not intended). Prefer passing it by constant reference:

  ```
  int binarySearch(int needle, const std::vector<int>& values)
  ```
- An idiomatic C++ would not pass the vector at all, but a pair of iterators (`first` and `last`). It immediately increases the usability of your code, because it becomes applicable to any random access container (e.g. `std::array`, C-style array, etc).

  A little bit more work (invoking `std::distance`) would make your code applicable to many more containers.
- `unsigned int` may not be wide enough to hold `std::vector.size()`. Use `std::vector::size_type`, or at least `size_t`.
- Declare variables is as narrow scope as possible. `value` is only uses inside the loop, and shall be declared there:

  ```
      int value = values.at(position);
  ```
- Most algorithms are expressed more naturally on the semi-open intervals, that is where the right bound does *not* belong to the range. At least, there would be no need for unintuitive `+ 1` in `middleOf`.
- `leftBound = leftBound` and `rightBound = rightBound` definitely raises some eyebrows. Don't do that.
- `middleOf` does not compute the middle of `left` and `right`. Instead it returns a half-baked result, which the caller has to use in further computations. Prefer returning the real middle:

  ```
  size_t middleOf(size_t left, size_t right) {
      return left + (right - left)/2;
  }
  ```

  Among other things, that would streamline the loop:

  ```
  {
      size_t middle = middleOf(left, right);
      if (values[middle] == needle) {
         return value;
      }
      if (values[middle] < needle) {
          right = middle;
      } else {
          left = middle + 1;
      }
  }
  ```
- Using `log` might indeed lead to the correct result, but it (a) complicates the analysis, and (b) is totally unnecessary. A natural condition to terminate the loop is `leftBound >= rightBound`.

Comment: the original `middleOf(..)` actually returns something which can be completely out of the search range: e.g. with  `leftBound=99` and `rightBound=100`, the original `middleOf()` will return `1`.

Comment: By "[pass] a pair of iterators", do you mean pass use `std::vector<int>::iterator iterator; iterator = myVector.begin();` and `myVector.end();`?

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, there's nothing wrong with this code. It's quite good how it is. There are a few minor things you could add, but if this came by me in a code review at work, I probably wouldn't have much to say. So here's what I can say:

## Use `const` for Things that Won't Change

You're already using `constexpr` for the constant in `binarySearch()`, but you also aren't going to modify either the `needle` or `values`. I would make them `const` to show the intent of their use in the function. I would also make `values` a `const` reference because it could potentially be copied and if it's large, that will be slow.

## Do All the Calculation in a Function

Your `middleOf()` function is named as if it should calculate the middle of the range that's passed to it. But it doesn't. You need to add `position` to the result returned from `middleOf()`. You should simply return the right value so the called doesn't need to add anything to it. I would define it like this:

```
unsigned int middleOf(const position, const int leftBound, const int rightBound) {
    return position + (rightBound - leftBound + 1) / 2;
}
```

Then it can be called like this:

```
position = middleOf(position, leftBound, rightBound);
```

You could also declare it `constexpr`.

## Naming

Overall your naming is pretty good. However, the meaning of the name `needle` is unclear. Is it a "needle in a haystack"? If so that's a bit of a stretch. I'd just name it something clear like `toFind` or `searchValue`.

Comment: Just a note: `needle` is a pretty classic name for this kind of algorithm that you'll find in a lot of algorithm books.  Not that there's any reason to not go with a more explicit name, but hey traditions are something ;)

Comment: It's true that `middleOf` is badly named. But your proposed method introduces a serious bug since you get wrong results in case of overflows. The correct solution for fixed size integers is to use `a + (b - a) / 2` assuming `a <= b` which is guaranteed here (well ok it'd be the correct solution for a half open interval, throw in the +1 if you want to make the code more complicated by using closed intervals).

Comment: D'oh! Yep, I see what you're saying about `middleOf()`. Fair point. In that case, they should pass in the position, left and right. I'll update it. As for `needle`, I've not heard that before (been programming professionally for 30 years), but it seems rather culturally specific.

Comment: Yeah I actually checked TAoCP and CLRS and neither uses `needle` in their section. So yeah, I'm certain that I've heard it in the past, but I couldn't even give you a source - so yeah, not that great a name :-) (Don't feel bad about the overflow bug though, that one was in a lot of production quality libraries - i.e. Java had it for much over a decade without anybody noticing..)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having to forward-declare the functions, put `main` at the bottom and generally define earlier in the file than use.

```
constexpr int NOT_FOUND = -1;
```

This is inside the function, so the callers of the function cannot make use of it.  The use of -1 is exposed anyway.

[⧺Enum.5](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#enum5-dont-use-all_caps-for-enumerators) *Don't use `ALL_CAPS` for enumerators* and [⧺ES.9](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es9-avoid-all_caps-names) *Avoid `ALL_CAPS` names*.

**good** (up to date best practice) for using `constexpr` instead of `static const` here.

```
int binarySearch(int needle, std::vector<int> values) {
```

Someone already pointed out that you are duplicating the vector for no reason.

```
const unsigned int length = values.size();
```

Good to remember the unchanging value rather than calling the function over and over, but don’t assume you know what type it is.  It is actually `size_t`, which is platform specific.  Use `auto` when declaring things, or look up the proper type to use.

```
const unsigned int maxIterations = ceil(log(length) / log(2)) + 1;
```

You do not need this!  The loop will end when the high and low index positions meet or cross.  I’ve never heard of an implementation that does this.

```
int value;
  ⋮
    value = values.at(position);
```

Declare the variable where you need it, not outside the loop.

```
unsigned int middleOf(int leftBound, int rightBound) {
    return (rightBound - leftBound + 1) / 2;
}
```

That doesn’t make sense.

```
unsigned int position = middleOf(leftBound, rightBound);
```

In this first use, you are assuming that `leftBound` is zero.

You should return the index between the two provided indexes.  You are returning half the size of the interval, which is not the "middle".

```
assert(-1 == binarySearch(3, values));
```

Your test cases will not run in a release build!  `assert` is a debug-only thing.  Suggest you look into [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2).

---

I’ve thought about binary searching myself, recently.  The classic logic taught in school is slow on a modern architecture because the `if` is essentially random, thus never predicted correctly.

I think a more efficient function would compute both possible new values (mid+1 and mid-1) and then use conditional moves to update the bounds.  No `else`, as only one of them will be triggered.

Looking at your code, you set

```
        leftBound = position;
```

or

```
        rightBound = position;
```

when you know for sure that `position` is in fact *out* of range.  Normally, this would be called `mid` and you set the updated left to mid-1, or right to mid+1.